# Xcode, sharing h / m files between projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use the same files in different projects.
I'd like to do this so that I can abstract some testing functionality away from my main project.

However, when I add files from my main project, #include calls in those files are using the files in the main project.

e.g. I have different constant.h files in both projects.

I really don't want to create a library / framework.
And I also don't want to have to make changes to the the files specific for one project.

How can I workaround this?

Comment: What do you mean by different project? Are u meaning different target under same project? Only target under same project can share files. Otherwise u need to copy paste or make framework.

Comment: I have projects in completely different folders. I have been able to add but not copy files, but I do have the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: Ur issue is not yet clear. What error u get?

Comment: That #included files are being used from the other project.

Comment: So both of ur projects are open in xcode at same time? I guess this is a not a good idea to use same physically located files in different project. One chage in file may break other project.

Comment: My issue is that I have file A which is shared between both projects. 

There's an #include to file B (found in project D) within file A. 

When I compile project F, it causes and error, that file B hasn't been found. 

This is because file B doesn't exist in project F.

Comment: Including file B under project F does not help?

Comment: Sorry, correction, it does find file B in project D when compiling project F, however I have my own cut down version, which it doesn't complain is missing. The error is the functionality in file B which is missing from project F. :(

Comment: U must add all dependent functionalities to build successfully. Thats how project build works. If you want to cut down some dependent links that wont work.

Comment: So what do I suggest I do, I was hoping to work on the same files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing same physical files in multiple project is not a good idea. Deleting or modifying from one project might break build for other projects. Moreover you must add all dependent functionalities and source in both projects to build successfully. Thats how project build works.

Suggestion

1. Always keep separate physical copy for separate projects
2. Even if you want to reuse physical files, make sure all dependencies are added. For example if file A uses file B, to add file A in a project, you must also add file B in the same project even though B has of no use for that project.